# Assertion on retrieving data from cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

i defined a class to map rows of a cassandra table:

```
case class Log(
    val time: Long,
    val date: String,
    val appId: String,
    val instanceId: String,
    val appName: String,
    val channel: String,
    val originCode: String,
    val message: String) {
}
```

i created an RDD to save all my tuples

```
 val logEntries = sc.cassandraTable[Log]("keyspace", "log")
```

to see if all works  i printed this:

```
println(logEntries.counts()) -> works, print the numbers of tuples retrieved.
println(logEntries.first()) -> exception on this line
```

> java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Missing columns needed by
>   com.model.Log: app_name, app_id, origin_code, instance_id

***my columns of table log on cassandra are:***

```
time bigint, date text, appid text, instanceid text, appname text, channel text, origincode text, message text
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [cassandra-spark-connector docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/4_mapper.md), column name mapper has it's own logic for converting case class parameters to column names:

> For multi-word column identifiers, separate each word by an underscore in Cassandra, and use the camel case convention on the Scala side.

So if you use `case class Log(appId:String, instanceId:String)` with camel-cased parameters, it will be automatically mapped to a **underscore-separated** notation: `app_id text, instance_id text`. It cannot be automatically mapped to `appid text, instanceid text`: you've missed an underscore.